# Source Code Appears to Be Hidden

Tags: javascript, view-source

I'm trying to debug a particular website (that I do not control, but I'm helping to debug) and I did find the problem, but ran into something I've not seen before and hoping someone can explain it. When viewing the source code of the page using Chrome's Javascript Console I see more code than when viewing the source with the built in browser "View Source" function.

I've searched around and think this may have something to do with "Javascript Encryption", but I'm not sure.

I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 4):

You cannot "view source" with Chrome's JavaScript console. You can only view the current state of the DOM. Any elements added by JavaScript will appear there, but not in the "view source" of page, hence the difference you're seeing.

Completely, totally unrelated to "Javascript Encryption".

Comment: Ok. I've never noticed scripts being added by javascript into the head of a website before. I'm not too familiar with javascript and should learn it. Back in the day when I did web design javascript and even css wasn't common yet. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like they're built in https://www.legalshield.com/assets/js/video-library.js .  Specifically, `var thumbnail_hostname = 'http://www.legalshield.com';` near the top of that script would need to be changed.

Comment: I noticed that url would need correcting too to fix all of the image thumbnail errors on the page. So, fixing that url should fix the bigger problem of the video-library.js content being blocked too?